# Finding the second largest number out of 10 numbers entered using a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

Exercise 10c, chapter 5, in Brian Heinold's *A Practical Introduction to Python Programming* reads:

Ask the user to enter 10 test scores. Write a program to do the following:
(c) Print out the second largest score.

Below is the code I used to find the **largest** one, however I don't see a way to modify the code so that it prints the second largest number. I tried to do something, but it doesn't work. The elements like def, min, max, append, etc. have not been covered in this chapter and the previous ones, therefore I think the author created this exercise for variable swapping purposes.
I'm really curious what the code should look like. There must be a technique or a lifehack that I'm missing. Please help me figure it out.
Thank you.

```
largest = eval(input('Enter score: '))
s_largest = 0
for i in range(3,11):
    num = eval(input('Enter score: '))
    if num > largest:
        largest = num
        if num < largest:
            s_largest = num
print(s_largest)
```

Comment: Don't use `eval()` to convert input to a number, use `int()` or `float()`.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that in other books. But this author sticks to eval so far. However, I guess that is not the reason th code is not working.

Comment: When `num > largest`, you should move `largest` to `s_largest`. Otherwise, when `num > s_largest`, you should copy `num` to `s_largest`.